# Sign up started from mobile web doesn’t allow to upload the profile picture

Tags: bug, mobile-web, uploader, sign-up

Actually there’s no mobile view Sign Up page, but if you started sign up process from mobile version of site there’s no option to upload the profile picture. It looks weird. Just spot the difference:

- full web

> [image: full web]

- mobile

> [image: mobile]